# Undefined id when assigning data after axios promise Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a function in methods that gets data using axios, the probem is when i assign to data property the id become undefined but other data returns fine.. I tried to console.log the data returned after promise the id's are shown but assigning it to data property it return undefined.

```
 data() {
        return {
            answers: [],
        }
    },
methods: {
        fetchAnswers() {
            // axios.get('/answers/' + this.questionId + '/question')
            axios.get(`/answers/${this.question.id}/question`)
                .then(({data}) => {
                        console.log(data.data)
                        // this.answers = data.data

                    }
                )
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
}
```

With commenting **this.answers** the result for console become
[image]

When i uncomment the result become
[image]

Comment: there should be no reason for that to happen. Is this always reproducible? Can you check the response at your server end which is processing the request?

Comment: @kiddorails, Thanks for reply.. the reponse from my API looks fine and the id's are shown

Comment: but do you mean to say, that your `console.log(data.data)` line is behaving differently based on comment and uncomment of line `this.answers = data.data` ??

Comment: yeah, and in fact i want data answers to have id's so that i can use it for other issues

Comment: From what you posted, it's unclear why this can happen. `id` doesn't differ from `vote_count` and it's unknown why one remains a number and another is undefined. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. If the problem is on client side and not in server response, this should be reproducible with static JSON like `Promise.resolve({ data: [...] }).then(...)`.

Comment: thanks, let me try